# I want to build NestJS app in javascript language but it give some error on tsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, nestjs-config

Can you help me how to build nestjs with language javascript?
i was create the nestjs app with "nest new --language js new-app-name", and i want to deploy it into vercel. i was try to build with nest build but it show an error message like this:
" Error  Could not find TypeScript configuration file "tsconfig.json". Please, ensure that you are running this command in the appropriate directory (inside Nest workspace)".
after read the message i check my files again and i found that i doesn't have tsconfig.json but i have an jsconfig.json.

so, is anybody have some soution with my problems?
i'll be glad if someone know how to fix it.
Thank you

i was try to change the command like:
"nest build --project jsconfig.json"
"nest build --jsonfig jsconfig.json"
"npm run build"

but it doesn't work

I expect my nestjs can build properly

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nest build` only works with `.ts` files. For writing and running a Nest application in regular JavaScript you'll need to use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) with the run command being `babel-node index.js`. There's no "building" to be done, so `nest build` won't do anything.